# COUNT function - multiple columns

Tags: dax

Im wishing to do a DAX COUNT measure where Column 1 = Jan-16 and Column 2 = BLANK. Im having problems with the BLANK syntax.

Comment: Post what you have so far and the error message and we can assist

Answer (score 1):

You can count the blank values by using `ISBLANK` function. I think this expression returns the needed count.

```
MeasureName:=
  COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(TableName;MONTH(TableName[Column1]) = 1 
      && ISBLANK(TableName[Column2])
    ) 
  )
```

The `MONTH(TableName[Column1]) = 1` part will filter the dates corresponding to the first month of the year, January. Detail the Column1 date type to provide the accurate answer.

> In case the expression throws error replace the `;` for `,` in the
>   filter function part. The common separator  is the comma but it could
>   vary based on regional settings and applications.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: typo in fitler function. FILTER(TableName,

Comment: @littlecegian, Note args separator in Excel depends on the OS regional settings. Technically this is not a typo because that is the correct separator for my regional setting, but thanks for pointing it I'll clear it since user could have a different setting or an application different than Excel.

Comment: Did not know about region specific delimiters. Good to know. I tried running your solution in ssms and everything worked fine except the semi-colon.